# What is kept after a character wipe?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I recently started playing *Elite: Dangerous* and have learned there will be a full (?) character wipe soon (November 22nd IIRC), so for this reason I've been holding back my urge to play it for the last couple of weeks.

Is there anything in the game that *does* gets carried over between wipes?

Comment: Sorry, we can't answer when the last wipe will happen.  We could, though, probably tell you what gets carried over through wipes, as I suspect there's been a few already, and answers can be based on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the last couple of wipes, **nothing in-game is kept.**

Local settings, e.g. key bindings and screen resolution, are kept.

Mistakes are wiped as well, so use this to your advantage! After all, your skills and knowledge about the game cannot be reset. So try things out: tweak your key bindings, dock with assisted flight off, fire at some law-enforcement forces, or dive into a star. And enjoy the fact that it doesn't matter for the real game :)

Comment: Thanks! What would be a reason to dock without Flight Assist? The challenge? :)

Comment: @villeman Yes, the challenge. It's just one example of challenges you could set for yourself.

Comment: @Tyralion: Flight assist can also help with a stealthy station entry.

Comment: FYI for anyone interested, there are now not going to be any more wipes before the release next week.